# How can I see which dataset is throwing me an error about a missing parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset, report, reporting

I'm getting a Server Error when trying to view a report on a remote server - it looks as though the deploy may have failed, because it works fine on my dev environment. The error I'm getting is:

> An attempt was made to set a data set parameter '@shopName' that is not defined in this data set.

However there are a large number of datasets associated with this report. How can I narrow it down to only the offending dataset; so that I can properly debug this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to see which dataset is causing the problem is to open the Report Server Service log file. This can be found at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles` for SQL Server 2014.

Open the newest `.log` file in the directory, and find the error message you saw earlier.

Above it you will see the name of the dataset causing the problem:

> An exception has occurred in data set 'getShopAddress'